# UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell touch event

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, touch

I have a uicollectionview inside a uitableviewcell. tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath doesn't recognize my touch and collectionView: didSelectItemAtIndexPath only recognizes touch for the items inside the collectionview. Is there a way for a uitableviewcell with a uicollectionview inside to recognize touch events?

Comment: You can try to use `hitTest:withEvent`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass UICollectionView touch event to its parent UITableViewCell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512344/pass-uicollectionview-touch-event-to-its-parent-uitableviewcell)