# Pass UICollectionView touch event to its parent UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

Here is the view structure:

The outer view is a `UITableView`.

Inside the `UITableViewCell`, there is a `UICollectionView`. And notice that there is some black spacing between the collection view cells.

When I tap the spacing in the UICollectionView, I want the touch event to pass to the `UITableViewCell`.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Excellent answer by @tounaobun. Tested and it works as expected:

1) If you tap anywhere on the collection view that is not an item, then the table cell underneath will select just fine.

2) if you tap on the items in the collection view, then the table cell will not select and you can interact with the collection view normally (aka, scrolling, invoking didSelectItem, etc)

I converted to swift for reference:

Swift 3:

```
class TableCellCollectionView: UICollectionView { 

 override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if let hitView = super.hitTest(point, with: event) {
        if hitView is TableCellCollectionView {
            return nil
        } else {
            return hitView
        }
    } else {
        return nil
    }

}
```

Just add this class definition to your code (I have it in a utility file) and then change the collection view's class from UICollectionView to TableCellCollectionView and you should be all set.

Comment: I have a similar situation: UICollectionViewCell inside of another UICollectionViewCell. However, I can only detect taps (via didSelectItem delegate method) from the cell containing the other cell. But I need to detect taps from the cell that is inside. This is not working.

Comment: @vikzilla have you found a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: @William Excellent solution, those who will understand this will definitely get benefit as this is the perfect solution for the above problem.

Answer (score 6):

After google around, I have found a solution.Just inherit `UICollectionView` class and override `hitTest:withEvent` method.

**CustomCollectionView.h**

```
@interface CustomCollectionView : UICollectionView

@end
```

**CustomCollectionView.m**

```
@implementation CustomCollectionView

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    if ([hitView isKindOfClass:[self class]]) {
        // If it is class UICollectionView,just return nil.
        return nil;
    }
    // else return super implementation.
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `point(inside:with:)` method of `UICollectionView` and manually check whether any cell contains specified point:

```
class CollectionView: UICollectionView {
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        visibleCells.contains(where: { $0.frame.contains(point) })
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Is that possible to set collectionView's backgroundView UserInteraction not enable, but make sure the collectionViewCell did, so that it could pass the tapEvent to next responder.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    theCollectionView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```

I hope it would help.

Comment: That way UICollectionViewCell can not respond to user interaction.